# Iterating an object to create a select with option groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I have an object like this:

```
{
  "Administration": {
    "5756":"AdminRelease 1",
    "8238":"AdminRelease 2",
    "8239":"AdminRelease 3"
  },
  "Office": {
    "6016":"AndroidRelease 1",
    "6017":"AndroidRelease 2",
    "6044":"AndroidRelease 4",
    "6019":"AndroidRelease 5"
  }
}
```

I am trying to iterate this within a `select` tag as a drop-down. I am trying to create an option group for say `Administration` and `Office` under which I will have respective release list as dropdown.

What I have done so far is this:

```
<select id="releaseDropdown_${widgetId}" onChange="renderChartWithData_${widgetId}">
  #if(!$releasesList.isEmpty())
    #foreach($pName in $releasesList.keySet())
      <optgroup label="${pName}">
        #foreach($key in $releasesList.keySet())
          #if("${defaultRelease}" == "${key}")
            <option value="${key}"selected="selected">
          #else
            <option value="${key}">
          #end
          $releasesList.values().get(${key})
          </option>
        #end
      </optgroup>
    #end
  #else
    <option value="0">No Release</option>
  #end
</select>
```

I am new to UI and unable to find mistake in my code. If there are syntax errors or logical errors.

Comment: This appears to be Server-Siude Scripting shown. JavaScript/jQuery is Client-Side scripting that is executed in the browser. Please clarify which type of scripting solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, you need to make up select elements based on your sourcing object. Maybe, following quick and dirty example will give you a hint as of how to achieve what's needed.

```js
var srcData = {
    "Administration":{
        "5756":"AdminRelease 1",
        "8238":"AdminRelease 2",
        "8239":"AdminRelease 3"
    },
    "Office":{
        "6016":"AndroidRelease 1",
        "6017":"AndroidRelease 2",
        "6044":"AndroidRelease 4",
        "6019":"AndroidRelease 5"
    }
};

Object.values(srcData).forEach((item, index) => {
  let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  let label = Object.keys(srcData)[index];
  wrapper.innerHTML += `<label>${label}</label>`;
  let selectHTML = '<select>';
  Object.values(item).forEach((option, index) => {
    selectHTML +=`<option value="${Object.keys(item)[index]}">${option}</option>`;
  });
  wrapper.innerHTML += selectHTML+'</select>';
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```